# How do I undo a default download program to an unsupported program?

Tags: windows-7, csv, notepad, default-settings, quickbooks

I am not tech-savy.

I was trying to download bank statements via csv file to upload them to quickbooks. I couldn't open them so I chose the default option as Notepad. I then realized that I shouldn't have done that because I was able to upload the file I couldn't open to quickbooks but not the one I set to Notepad. Now I don't know how to undo that, or if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A file saved by Notepad is a [plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) file, just like a [.CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. Right-click on that file, choose the first tab (Properties) and look in the file name box up top; does the file you saved end in .CSV or in .TXT ? If it ends in .TXT , rename it to end in .CSV and QB will now accept it.